# How to get virtkey value for WM_KEYDOWN in WS_CHILD?

Tags: c, winapi

I want to know the value of virtual key pressed when a child window(like 'edit' or 'button') has focus.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one way is to use

```
WNDPROC g_OldProc;

LRESULT CALLBACK MyEditWindowProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    if ( uMsg == WM_KEYDOWN )
    {
         // Handle key down.
    }
    return g_OldProc( hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );
}
```

then at some opportune moment

```
g_OldProc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLongPtr( hEdit, GWLP_WNDPROC );
SetWindowLongPtr( hEdit, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)MyEditWindowProc );
```

This will replace the window procedure of the hEdit control with your own window procedure that, in turn, calls the original window procedure.

Comment: I'm assuming that SetClassLongPtr does not work because I use it on 'base' classes like 'button'.

Comment: I would assume SetClassLongPtr only affects windows created after the call.  I don't KNOW on that one though.  I've never had call to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could catch them at the level of the message loop (before calling DispatchMessage). Nasty but will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [GetKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646301%28VS.85%29.aspx) Win32 API from within a [WM_SETFOCUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646283%28VS.85%29.aspx) handler.